# Firebase Value event listener not responding

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am new to Firebase .  I think I have done it all right,here is my code ,I don't know  why this function is not working.

```
 database!!.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
       override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {

       }

       override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
          var name=p0!!.child("name").value.toString()
           var status=p0.child("Status").value.toString()
           var image=p0.child("image").value.toString()
           var thumbimage=p0.child("thumbimage").value.toString()
           nameid.setText(name)
           statusid.setText(status)
           if(!image!!.equals("null")){
               Picasso.with(applicationContext)
                       .load(image)
                       .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
                       .into(circleImageView)


           }
       }

   })
```

Comment: why do you think it's not working? are you seeing any errors? The function is asynchronous so the reponse will come later when firebase db responds, it will not return any result immediately

Comment: No I am calling this listener in the create method of an activity so all the field of that activity should get updated if it is working

Comment: try printing stuff inside onCancelled, maybe that's getting called and you are actually hitting some error.

Comment: Yes ,It is getting cancelled but don't know why

Comment: print the database error buddy... can't help you without knowing what's going on... might be a security exception, might be something else... there's a ton of issues which can cause it to cancel.

Comment: permission denied is the error

Comment: Alright that narrows it down, it's a security rule that you have for your db which is causing it to fail. Post your security rules of the rtdb here. Also let me know if you use any kind of Firebase Auth logins or not?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Yes i have use email as auth login

Comment: Give read permissions to all or as per your wish. right now i don't see a read permission, so i think rtdb is considering it false and not allowing reads. add a read permission to your security rule similar to the write one

Comment: Also note, your current rules will only allow you to read the data under users/uid where the uid will be equal to your auth user

Comment: @AbdusSamad You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49650677/edit) you question to inlcude your database rules, the error(s) you are getting and where you attach your listener to.

Comment: Thanks @Kushan it works